# The type 'Expando' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, reference, visual-studio-2015, .net-assembly

I'm getting the following compile error:

```
The type 'Expando' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. 
You must add a reference to assembly 'Westwind.Utilities, Version=2.64.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6f7d66a3bb7de652'.
```

The thing is, I have a reference to that version of the assembly... I think the problem is due to a class library.

My ClassLibrary has the following class:

```
public class Generic_AnswerFile : Expando { ... }
```

and my Test Console has the following class:

```
public class Specific_AnswerFile : Generic_AnswerFile { ... }
```

The Specific_AnswerFile will not compile. Any ideas why? Both projects are .Net 4.0 and have references to the correct .Net 4.0 version of Westwind.Utilities 2.64

Comment: If you say both projects have the reference, inspect the csproj files, check if there is any possibly relevant difference in how the references are specified.

Answer (score 0):

The type Expando is defined in his assembly

that means only in the GAC. though you have reference to it.. but it would fail to load. To load it properly you need to define it in your config file under assembly tag

```
<add assembly="Expando, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[MyPublicKeyToken]"/>
```